# WPF DataGrid : Avoid Cell selection on RightClick

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

**I am trying to disable the right click in a cell in a WPF DataGrid from selecting it and at the same time I want to bind context menu from my ParentWindow(MFC)** so that my overall application will have same ContextMenu

if i do **e.Handle=True in previewMouseRightButtonUp then right click event doesnt reach my parentWindow(MFC)**

can anyone help me to fix this issue

same issue i have raised in [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cf20ecc6-1c05-496f-b5bb-e2a2a130c427/wpf-datagrid-avoid-cell-selection-on-rightclick?forum=wpf)

ThankYou

Santhosh Devi

Answer (score 0):

In your `DataGrid` subscribe to the event

```
SelectionChanged += SelectionChangedHandler;
```

and "disable" the selection.

```
void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UnselectAllCells();
}
```

Comment: I want to Keep my previous selectedCell only i dont want to select cell on mouse right click.If i do unselectallcells it will clear all my previous selectedItems which was done via mouseLeft button down

Comment: is your context menu requires previously selected Cell value?